# What is the meaning of the words with underline in a man page?

Tags: manpage

For most commands that I have seen, there are some underlined words in their `man` page. What is the meaning of this underline? Is that a link? If yes, how we can go there?

Comment: ["The underline is just a highlight, there is no "link" involved.

The normal `man` page reader is just a text formater. In fact `man` doesn't even display the text, `man` just formats it and sends it to another text display program to be shown on the screen (usually `less`). These programs have no concept of links."](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18151/how-to-follow-links-in-linux-man-pages)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most underlined words in man pages are for **emphasis**. Its is not a hyperlink .

Comment: "Most underlined words..." -> what about the other ones?

Answer (score 14):

also from **man man** page

```
   italic text        replace with appropriate argument.
   [-abc]             any or all arguments within [ ] are optional.
   -a|-b              options delimited by | cannot be used together.

   argument ...       argument is repeatable.
   [expression] ...   entire expression within [ ] is repeatable.

   Exact rendering may vary depending on the output device.  For instance,
   man will usually not be able to render italics when running in a termi‐
   nal, and will typically use underlined or coloured text instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Italics (emphasis; as clearly answered above, they are usually displayed underlined, unfortunately) are used in several sections of a manual page for different purposes.

```
In the synopsis, boldface is used for as-is text and italics are used to
indicate  replaceable  arguments.

For  manual  pages  that describe a command (typically in Sections 1 and 8),
the arguments are always specified using italics, even in the SYNOPSIS section.

For manual pages that describe functions (typically in Sections 2  and  3),
the arguments  are  always  specified  using  italics, even in the SYNOPSIS section,
where the rest of the function is specified in bold:

       int myfunction(int argc, char **argv);

Variable names should, like argument names, be specified in italics.
```

General formatting conventions:

```
If  the  command is short, then it can be included inline in the text, in italic
format, for example, man 7 man-pages.  In this case, it may be worth using  non‐
breaking  spaces  ("\ ")  at  suitable  places  in the command.  Command options
should be written in italics (e.g., -l).

Expressions, if not written on a separate indented line, should be specified  in
italics.  Again, the use of nonbreaking spaces may be appropriate if the expres‐
sion is inlined with normal text.
```

Consult **man-pages**(7) for more details.